# Ubuntu don't recognizes wifi on macbook 13

Tags: wireless, macbook

it's not a question, but a solution, after one day i got the goddamn thing!

Well, how you can see in title, my ubuntu cannot solve the problem. some dramatics solution i found: reintall all ubuntu...

But there's a better way. You can try to buy a wifi adapter plug and play (i found a old one in my house) and install the package: sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source (with internet, of course) and here we go, i got then!

obs: $lspci -nn | grep 0280 >>
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM4360 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:43a0] (rev 03)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers)  your device is listed there